# Cloudera Manager 5.9 Installation

Tags: cloudera-manager

I am trying to install Cloudera Manager 5.9 . I did a

```
 sudo service cloudera-scm-server status

 Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Sat 2017-01-14 16:32:57 UTC; 21min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Note : When starting the service I am getting the following error:

/etc/rc.d/init.d/cloudera-scm-server: line 109: pstree: command not found

I am not able to access CM UI from browser. My cloudera-scm-server.log and cloudera-scm-server.out file dont contain any error logs.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? Kindly help me with this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the server-db status..?

Comment: Yes I did check the db status. Its running. I was able to login with the credentials configured for cloudera manager server database. I have checked selinux status also. It is disabled. Still facing the issue

Comment: Did you check the firewalls and iptables and how you are accessing the webUI

Comment: Actually I am trying this out in AWS. I have opened firewalls and disabled iptables. I am not able to access webUI. Since CM is in active(exited) status.

Answer (score -1):

Install the psmisc package to get pstree command